# pull variable from css with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get an action to occur when one clicks on an image, however only when the image is at full opacity

```js
function func() {
  if ($('.Absolute-Center').css('opacity') == 1) {
    alert("it works");
  }
}
```

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
img.Absolute-Center {
  opacity: 0.05;
  filter: alpha(opacity=5);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 20s linear;
}
img.Absolute-Center:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 20s linear;
}
```

```html
<img src="picture.png" class="Absolute-Center" onclick="func()" />
```

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library? It works for me when including the library [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mw3dghj/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `transitionend` event , `.addClass()` , `.removeClass()` ; removing `:hover` from `css`

```js
function func(e) {
  if ($(this).css("opacity") == 1) {
    alert("it works");
    $(this).removeClass("clicked")
  }
};

$(".Absolute-Center").on({
  "click": function() {
    $(this).addClass("clicked")
  },
  "transitionend": func
})
```

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
img.Absolute-Center {
  opacity: 0.05;
  filter: alpha(opacity=5);
  transition: opacity 20s linear;
}
img.Absolute-Center.clicked {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  transition: opacity 20s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" class="Absolute-Center" />
```

Comment: Thanks guest271314, it seems to work great, however when i integrate it into my page I get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, which refers to $(".Absolute-Center")

Comment: @Maccmiles Try wrapping `js` at post within `$(document).ready(function{})` block , see http://plnkr.co/edit/lD7es9fhppc2QDSkih7W?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This should help improve understanding and should be easily adaptable to do exactly what you want.

```js
$(function() {
  $('img').on('click', function() {
    var alpha = $(this).css('opacity');
    $("#msg").text((alpha == 1) ? "full" : alpha);
  }).on('transitionend', function() {
    var alpha = $(this).css('opacity');
    if (alpha == 1) {
      $("#msg2").fadeIn().delay(700).fadeOut();
    } else {
      $("#msg3").fadeIn().delay(700).fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
img {
  opacity: 0.05;
  filter: alpha(opacity=5);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 5s linear;
}
img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 5s linear;
}
#msg2, #msg3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="picture.png" />
<div>Last clicked at opacity: <span id="msg"></span>
</div>
<div id="msg2">End of fade-IN transition</div>
<div id="msg3">End of fade-OUT transition</div>
```